# PHP date reformat function

Tags: php

I am currently working on an app and have some issues with the date handling.
Found a simple solution, and want your opinion.
First thing, that I want to achieve:

1. I have 2 date format inputs, one is like 2013-09-30 14:20:00 and the other is 30/09/2013 1420
2. Time stamp is given with no day light saving time.

So, I have to store my date/time in DB with the same format in order to compare one with each other, and also I need to adjust the time stamp +1 hour if it is in the DST period.
For this, I made the following function:

```
function format_date($date_string, $date_format)
{
$unix = mktime( substr($date_string, strpos($date_format, 'HH'), 2),
                (strpos($date_format, 'ii'))? substr($date_string, strpos($date_format, 'ii'), 2) : '00',
                (strpos($date_format, 'ss'))? substr($date_string, strpos($date_format, 'ss'), 2) : '00',
                substr($date_string, strpos($date_format, 'MM'), 2),
                substr($date_string, strpos($date_format, 'DD'), 2),
                substr($date_string, strpos($date_format, 'YYYY'), 4)
            ) ;
$human = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unix);
$dst = date('I', $unix);

return (object)array(
                'unix' => $unix,
                'human' => $human,
                'dst' => $dst
                );
}

//Usage:
$date1 = format_date('2013-09-30 14:20','YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii');
$date2 = format_date('30/09/2013 1420','DD/MM/YYYY HHii');

echo $date1->human ;
echo '<br />';
echo $date2->human ;
echo '<br />';
//  $date1->human is the same with $date1->human, also ->unix
```

Maybe this will help others, but if you find something not right in this function please let me know before I put it in production.

Update: (thank you Glavić)

```
function format_date1($date_string, $date_format)
{
$date_build = DateTime::createFromFormat ( $date_format , $date_string  );
return (object)array(
                'unix' => $date_build->format('U'),
                'human' => $date_build->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'dst' => $date_build->format('I')
                );
}
$make_date = format_date1('30/09/2013 1420', 'd/m/Y Hi');
print_r($make_date); 
//returns stdClass Object ( [unix] => 1380540000 [human] => 2013-09-30 14:20:00 [dst] => 1 )
//Use: $make_date->unix | $make_date->human | $make_date->dst
```

Comment: You should take a look at [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Aha! good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method to convert datetime strings to DateTime object:

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', '2013-09-30 14:20');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y Hi', '30/09/2013 1420');
```

Now you can just format your output:

```
echo 'unix  : ' . $date1->format('U') . "\n";
echo 'human : ' . $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
echo 'dst   : ' . $date1->format('I') . "\n";
```

And you don't need to adjust timestamp for `+1 hour` if in DST, DateTime can handle leap years and DST correctly. Set timezone when you create DateTime object, or [change timezone after](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php).

Comment: I can not make the correction DST work as desired...
My input date is in let`s say GMT+2 (which means no DST) when in DST it is +1 hour, the output should be +1h

Comment: DateTime objects work with timezones. [Every timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) chooses to follow DST or not. [How to find out if timezone observes DST or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1586628/67332) [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) is also a good read.

Comment: [Example of DST change](https://eval.in/51923) for `UTC` (no DST) and `Europe/Berlin` (with DST).